# Foreign_Key reference to part of Composite Primary_Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have three tables as follows:

```
Country
{ 
    CountryCode Char(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CountryName VARCHAR(50)
}

PostalCode
{ 
    PostalCode VARCHAR(10),
    CountryCode Char(3),

    CONSTRAINT PK_PostalCode 
        PRIMARY KEY (PostalCode,CountryCode)
}

Ticket
{ 
    TicketID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PostalCode VARCHAR(10),
    CountryCode Char(3)   
}
```

I was easily able to make `CountryCode` in `Ticket` table a foreign key reference to `Country` table:

```
ALTER TABLE Ticket 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CountryCode
    FOREIGN KEY (CountryCode) REFERENCES Country(CountryCode);
```

But when I try to set `PostalCode` in the `Ticket` table as a foreign key reference to `PostalCode` table:

```
ALTER TABLE Ticket 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PostalCode
    FOREIGN KEY (PostalCode) REFERENCES PostalCode(PostalCode);
```

I get an error message:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'PostalCodes' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_PostalCode'

I knew it is because `PostalCode` is part of a composite PK in `PostalCode` table - how can I solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it in here, I will edit the post accordingly

Comment: If you can add the 'Unique' and 'Not Null' constraints to the PostalCode, then it can be used as a Candidate Key, otherwise you cannot have a FK on that column.

Comment: You need to do `FOREIGN KEY (PostalCode,CountryCode) REFERENCES PostalCode(PostalCode,CountryCode);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ***CANNOT*** reference only part of a primary key - it's an **all or nothing** choice with no middle ground: either you reference the **WHOLE** primary key (by using both `PostalCode` ***and*** `CountryCode` in your foreign key) like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Ticket 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PostalCode
    FOREIGN KEY (PostalCode, CountryCode) REFERENCES PostalCode(PostalCode, CountryCode);
```

or then you **DO NOT** reference the `PostalCode` table at all.

Comment: Yes, but in this case (if I reference the whole) I will not be able to make the CountryCode itself as a foreign key right?

Comment: @AhmedAli: sure you can - why shouldn't you be able to do that?? The `CountryCode` column can be part of more than one single FK constraint, if you wish to do so....